# Use SQLite database file in both .NET Maui project and WorkerService

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, maui, worker-service

I currently have a .NET Maui desktop project using a SQLite database. The database file is stored within that project. In the same VS solution I have a WorkerService project that is retrieving data from that file. I have been able to create and test this using the absolute path of the database file but haven't been able to set the path up to be found correctly when publishing. I am not sure if I should be attempting to relocate the file or find a better/correct way to set the relative path. The end goal is to publish the MauiProject msix and include the worker service. Below is the current solution and db file location.

ADIOrderTracker\ADIOrderTracker\ADIOrderTracker.db

[image]

```
string baseDir = "ADIOrderTracker";
string mauiProjectDirectory = Path.Combine(baseDir, @"ADIOrderTracker\ADIOrderTracker.db");
string databaseFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(mauiProjectDirectory);
_logger.LogInformation($"Database file path: {databaseFilePath}");

string connectionString = $"Data Source={databaseFilePath};";
```

Comment: SQLite is fine for a desktop application to use privately, but adding another process that needs to access the database necessitates a fundamental architectural change. SQLite is not designed for multiple processes to access the database. One process at a time has control over the file. You need to use a server-based database, like SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, etc. And once you do that, your WPF application shouldn't be connecting directly to it.; that's asking for trouble. You need an API in between them for your desktop application to call.

Comment: It's probably not a bad idea to have the worker service use the API, too, to control all database actions through that one point.

Comment: @madreflection From what I have been able to find this should be ok given only a single application is writing to the database. I am only reading in data using the worker service, also the worker service is a relatively quick process that is meant to be run once every morning with a task scheduler. It is hard to imagine a single select query from a different process would cause any issue in the sense you are referring to.

Comment: Even if only one is writing, a separate process reading at the same time will be locked out until the write is done. Furthermore, a file owned by the desktip application can be protected, such as by sandboxing, but you can't do that if the worker service can access it. I stand by my point: SQLite is no longer a viable technology for your projects.

Comment: @madreflection I understand your points. In many or most enterprise scenarios they would most likely be important. But this is a single select query that, even in the highly unlikely case it is executed during a write process from my application, would be delayed by fractions of a second as the only consequence. The security of this is something the client is aware of and not a downgrade from the current process. Would you have any feedback as to the possibility of the proposed scenario? A big factor in this is the prevention of using any network hosting which has led to the current situation

Comment: The last sentence actually makes things harder for you. If it's running on the same machine as the desktop app and trying to send e-mails from there, you could run into a wide range of problems you weren't prepared to solve. And if you have it installed on multiple systems, each system would have its own database... and its own worker service? Is each installation expected to work completely in isolation from all others? Or will there only ever be one installation? Even then, my only feedback is that while it's technically possible, it's architecturally far too fragile, ...

Comment: ...which is why I tried to steer you toward a more reliable architecture.

Comment: @madrelection If it is technically possible, and you have or know of that solution, then that would be very helpful. The architecture of the solution was not necessarily why I posted and I can take those things into consideration. At the moment they aren't particularly helpful to the issue.

Comment: I don't have a specific solution, just a vague notion, and I can't justify the time setting up a project that *might* resemble what you have in order to validate it. Maybe someone else will.